# Really poor performance when using subquery to get one value

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

Hi I have a table defined like below (Its actually lots of partition tables)

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_values
(
  ts             TIMESTAMPTZ(35, 6)                    NOT NULL,
  value          FLOAT8(17, 17) DEFAULT 'NaN' :: REAL  NOT NULL,
  sensor_id      INT4(10)                              NOT NULL,
  status         TRIDIUM_STATUS(max) DEFAULT 'unknown' NOT NULL,
  original_value FLOAT8(17, 17)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sensor_values_sensor_id_timestamp_index
  ON sensor_values (sensor_id, ts);
CREATE INDEX sensor_values_sensor_id_timestamp_value_index
  ON sensor_values (sensor_id, ts, value);
```

I am try to get the last days values grouped by sensor_id and day

```
SELECT sensor_id, ts::date, MIN(ts), MAX(ts), MIN(value), MAX(value) FROM sensor_values
  WHERE ts >= '2021-03-22 00:00:00+00:00' GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Works acceptable. I was hoping for better . I am guessing I should have a partial index on the day to speed things up. The explain analyze is shown at

https://explain.depesz.com/s/jYsM

If I add a sub query to get the day to start selecting the time is much worst

```
SELECT sensor_id, ts::date, MIN(ts), MAX(ts), MIN(value), MAX(value) FROM sensor_values
  WHERE ts >= (SELECT MAX(day) + INTERVAL '1 days' FROM sensor_values_days_private LIMIT 1) GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

https://explain.depesz.com/s/1o4I

Is the way I can make postgres understand that the subquery returns an unchanging constant and
make it equal in time taken to the first query ?

Am I right in thinking I need a partial index for the datetime column ?

Thanks

Comment: *Is the way I can make postgres understand that the subquery returns an unchanging constant* Move the subquery to FROM clause. `SELECT sensor_id, ts::date, MIN(ts), MAX(ts), MIN(value), MAX(value) FROM sensor_values CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(day) + INTERVAL '1 days' criteria FROM sensor_values_days_private LIMIT 1) subquery WHERE sensor_values.ts >= subquery.criteria GROUP BY 1, 2;`

Comment: The reason I am selecting multiple ts values is to eventually match another tables cols with a union. (I maintain a days table that gets updated at midnight each day). The union will merge old days with live data eventually.

Comment: Strangely moving the subquery to the from cause took 15m 20s to run

Comment: Strange... Try to move it to CTE.

Comment: @GlennPierce What does your new query look like (add it to your post) after moving the subquery to the `FROM` clause?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sensor_values_sensor_id_timestamp_index
  ON sensor_values (sensor_id, ts);
CREATE INDEX sensor_values_sensor_id_timestamp_value_index
  ON sensor_values (sensor_id, ts, value);
```

You can do instead:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sensor_values_sensor_id_timestamp_index
  ON sensor_values (sensor_id, ts) INCLUDE (value);
```

This will create your unique constraint index, and store "value" in it too, since I assume you want to use that as a covering index. Drop the second index, which is now useless. You can use the reclaimed disk space to create an index on (ts) which will help your query for the last day's records.

> Am I right in thinking I need a partial index for the datetime column ?

You can't create a partial index with a variable where clause like "current day".

But you can create it only on the last partition only.

Comment: Why  can you only create it on the last partition  ?

Comment: You can create on any partition, but do you really need it on all partitions?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I created a function

```
create or replace function last_sensor_values_days_day_updated() returns TIMESTAMPTZ AS
$$
SELECT (MAX(day) + INTERVAL '1 day')::TIMESTAMPTZ FROM sensor_values_days_private LIMIT 1;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

AND use it like

```
SELECT sensor_id, ts::date, MIN(ts), MAX(ts), MIN(value), MAX(value) FROM sensor_values
  WHERE ts >= last_sensor_values_days_day_updated() GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Seems like a hack and I don't know why it works but its fast.

I also speed things up a lot by adding an index just on sensor_id

Comment: It works because you made it IMMUTABLE so postgres knows its result will be constant, so it executes it to get the constant value before planning the rest of the query.